# Regularly extract text between pattern from text file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a huge text file (10GB) formatted as follow (multimodel PDB file):

```
Model 1
... (some text)
ENDMDL
Model 2
... (some text)
ENDMDL
Model 3
... (some text)
ENDMDL
...
Model 9999
... (some text)
ENDMDL
End
```

I know how to extract each model to a separate file:

```
while read line; do
    echo "${line}" >> model_${i}.pdb
    [[ ${line[0]} == ENDMDL ]] && ((i++))
done < $pdb
```

Now, I need to extract the models in a discrete way in steps of `N`. The idea is that if `N=5`, then extract the model 1, then the model 6, then model 11, etc.

A note: the number after the word `Model`, cannot be used as reference as can be duplicated due to standard issue with multimodels [PDB](http://www.wwpdb.org/documentation/file-format-content/format33/v3.3.html) files.

Comment: you have `...` after one of the ENDMDL, is it a typo? or is it expected there may be irregularities

Comment: @bac0n I think he meant "a lot of similar records", but it's indeed confusing.

Comment: It means a lot of similar records.

Comment: FWIW `csplit` could probably be used more efficiently than your shell loop to split every model to a separate file ex. `csplit -sz -f model_ -b '%d.pdb' file.pdb '/^ENDMDL/+1' '{*}'`

Comment: ... unfortunately (unlike `split` - which would be an option if `... (some text)` consists of a known, fixed number of lines), `csplit` doesn't appear to have a "Kth of N" feature.

Comment: Extract model number 1 first then you can check for the remainder of the division of **$i** devided by **5** `expr $i % 5` then when the result is **one**, that is when the next model should be extracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `awk`, using the `ENDMDL` marker as the record separator and modulo arithmetic to pick the records:

```
awk -v skip=5 'BEGIN{ORS = RS = "\nENDMDL\n"} !((NR-1)%skip)' file.pdb
```

or (to write each extracted model to a separate file)

```
awk -v skip=5 '
  BEGIN {ORS = RS = "\nENDMDL\n"} 
  !((NR-1)%skip) {f = sprintf("model_%d.pdb", NR); print > f; close(f)}
' file.pdb
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked to create a temporary file with the extraction. Then I used to extract the individual files.

Comment: @Camps I added a variant that writes each extracted model to a separate file

Answer (score 1):

**In bash!**

> Change `n=5` to for example `n=6` to extract the model 1, then the
> model 7, then model 13, etc.

To print output in terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
n=5

while read line
        do
                r=$((i % n))
                if [[ "$line" =~ "ENDMDL" ]] && [ "$r" -eq 1 ]
                        then
                        echo "$line"

                        ((i++))
                elif [ "$r" -eq 1 ]
                        then
                        echo "$line"
                elif [[ "$line" =~ "ENDMDL" ]]
                        then
                        ((i++))
                fi
        done < file.pdb
```

Or to write directly to split files:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
n=5

while read line
        do
                r=$((i % n))
                if [[ "$line" =~ "ENDMDL" ]] && [ "$r" -eq 1 ]
                        then
                        echo "$line" >> model_"$i".pdb

                        ((i++))
                elif [ "$r" -eq 1 ]
                        then
                        echo "$line" >> model_"$i".pdb
                elif [[ "$line" =~ "ENDMDL" ]]
                        then
                        ((i++))
                fi
        done < file.pdb
```

Comment: This also worked but the time running (for extracting only 5 models) is the same as when extracting all of them.

Comment: @Camps That is unlikely. How did you modify the script to just extract five models? Did you break out of the while loop after extracting the five models? Because otherwise it will continue reading the whole file. Time should be much less for extracting just five models.

Comment: The big file has 20001 models. I set `n=5000`, then, only five models where extracted.

Comment: @Camps This way yes. You are right. Unfortunately this is how it works reading and processing line by line no matter what the value of `n=` is.